# Como abrir una pagina con una posición scroll con javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

como abrir una pagina con una posicion scroll, por ejemplo

quiero abrir una pagina desde una lista despegable de etiquetas

- imagenes

  - imagen1

    imagen2

    imagen3

cada etiqueta me lleva a la misma pagina pero por ejemplo al dar click a imagen 2 que me lleve a la pagina hasta donde esta la imagen 2 que es mas o menos hasta la mitad de toda la pagina,como hacerlo con Jquery?

Comment: cada etiqueta abre una pagina nueva

Comment: Hola Julian, bienvenido! Para poder ayudarte de mejor manera necesitamos ver que has intentado y en que estás fallando, para mas información te sugiero leer [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), aparte de terminar el [recorrido del sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y obtener tu primera medalla!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas colocar un identificador a los elementos a los que quieres dirigirte.

```
<div id="pagina1">Página 1</div>
<div id="pagina2">Página 2</div>
<div id="pagina2">Página 3</div>
```

Y para que al clicar en las imágenes vaya a la posición de los identificadores necesitarás añadir un link a tus imagenes referenciado al identificador de la página a la que quieres ir

```
<a href="#pagina1">Imagen 1</a>
<a href="#pagina2">Imagen 2</a>
<a href="#pagina3">Imagen 3</a>
```